# bcrypt.hash doesn't call its callback

Tags: node.js, bcrypt

For some reason the `bcrypt.hash` method hangs up and never calls its callback.

```
bcrypt.genSalt(29, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) {
        res.json({ success: false, msg: err.message });
    } else {
        bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, function (err, hash) {
            // This function is never called
            res.json({ success: true });
        });
    }
});
```

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

It seems it isn't related with express.js & so on.
I just have created a script file `test.js`:

```
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

var pwd = 'Test password 123';

bcrypt.genSalt(29, function(err, salt) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('1: ' + err.message);
    } else {
        console.log('Salt: ' + salt);
        bcrypt.hash(pwd, salt, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('2: ' + err.message);
            } else {
                console.log('Hash: ' + hash);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Then I start it by the use of `node test.js`. It outputs a salt, after that it hangs up and the bcrypt.hash doesn't call its callback function in any case with error or not. I am working on OS X and I have the node v7.8.0 installed.

Comment: Is the first callback throwing an error?  Also, is req.body.password defined?  I assume this is sitting inside of some endpoint, but don't see the code for that.

Comment: @user2263572 1. No. 2. Yes

Comment: @user2263572 I have made an update

Answer (score 8, accepted):

29 salt rounds means `Math.pow(2, 29)` key expansion rounds, which will take ages.

To illustrate:

- 10 rounds takes about 78ms on my MBP
- 12 rounds takes about 300ms
- 14 rounds takes about 1170ms
- 16 rounds takes about 4700ms

You might be able to do the math to calculate how long it would take to use 29 rounds (it's somewhere along the line of 2.6 million seconds, or about a month).

Comment: For some reason I was sure that 29 - is a length of a salt string. Now it seems I've started to understand. Thanks! )

Comment: Thanks very much - I did not realize the rounds were that expensive! Geesh